# Tense of a verb

Tags: wordnet

How do i find in wordnet 
or with a tool the tense of a verb ?

for example given:

input: happened -> output : past

input: will happen -> output: future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with WordNet. Try the [NodeBox Linguistics](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics):

Input:

```
print en.verb.tense("was")
```

Output:

```
>>> 1st singular past
```