# Java: Convert an English verb to a particular tense

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

Is there a way to convert an English verb to a particular tense with java?

for example:

```
convertToPast("go"); //will give went
convertToCtn("go"); //will give going
```

I have used Stanford nlp and WordNet with JAWS.

Comment: Are you trying to create something from scratch?

Comment: This may have been answered already.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575873/tense-of-a-verb

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520501/how-do-you-get-the-past-tense-of-a-verb). Solved using [SimpleNLG library](https://code.google.com/p/simplenlg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [this library](https://code.google.com/p/simplenlg/)

for more details refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520501/how-do-you-get-the-past-tense-of-a-verb)

Comment: But, I could only change the world in to present, past, future.
How to convert to continuous form, like "going"

Comment: ok http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758226/present-participle-form-of-run-is-runing-in-simplenlg solved the -ing problem

Comment: @BuntuLinux do you remember, what the solution was? that link no longer works...

Comment: @mrnoobynoob https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg